# How to generate pdf with PHP using wkhtml2pdf?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

How I write PHP to generate PDF from PHP page using wkhtml2pdf ? I am looking for only an example also my server is Linux at godaddy how I can decide which kind of Linux ?

Other suggestions that wkhtml2pdf are welcome

Comment: For memory, godaddy don't allow you to run external scripts or binaries.  You won't be able to run wktml2pdf on your server.

Comment: thanks Luke Park, any other PDF library to use ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a VPS from digitalocean or a VPS from the provider you desire with root access. I used Debian and CentOS without problems. As for today, use the binary from the site because it contains the patched QT version and will eliminate the issues with zoom feature.
I created a gist with minimal sample code to output pdf file to browser here https://gist.github.com/alpenzoo/b3d4b2ae144d00fe2b8d442d03d7fd50